# Putting content into a frame at design time

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I have a brand new Windows Phone 8.1 app with a mainpage:

```
<Grid>
  <Frame>
    <local:BlankPage1 />
  </Frame>
</Grid>
```

and BlankPage1 is just a blank Page with a textblock on it. This works fine in Windows 8.1 but in Windows Phone 8.1 it throws a null pointer exception when the window is activated.

Isn't this valid syntax?

I would like to have a frame on my Mainpage in which I use Frame.Navigate to map pages, handling all the navigation myself.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a Frame element to call Frame.Navigate.

`Window.Current.Content` can be cast to a `Frame` element.

```
var f = (Frame)Window.Current.Content;
f.Navigate(...);
```